# Normalised Weapon Damage Formula

Tags: c#, math, formula

I would like to create a balanced weapon Formula as the start for the damage output of the player. Other factors will be stacked on this formula, but i would like a base to start with.

So what i am looking for is a formulae that lets different types of weapons deal the same damage over a 10 second interval.

For example, my assault rifle has an rpm of 700 which makes it shoot 11 times per second.

Whereas my pistol has an rpm of 120 which makes it shot twice per second.

I want to calculate how much damage each weapon does on each shot to accumulate For example, 200 damage in 10 seconds, regardless of fire rate.

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Write tests out of with these requirements. Then try to implement the function to satisfy the tests.

Comment: Wrong board, should be on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the total damage per minute is supposed to be costant for each weapon, then `damage per shot = damage per minute / rate of fire`

Keep in mind that balancing purely with DPS is a poor method. Other factors like accuracy, reload speed, clip size, etc. should and will influence gameplay and effectiveness.